# Golang xml unmarshal html table

Tags: html, xml, go, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I have a simple HTML table, and want to get all cell values even if it's  HTML code inside.

Trying to use xml unmarshal, but didn't get the right struct tags, values or attributes.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type XMLTable struct {
XMLName xml.Name `xml:"TABLE"`
    Row []struct{
        Cell string `xml:"TD"`
    }`xml:"TR"`
}

func main() {
    raw_html_table := `
    <TABLE><TR>
    <TD>lalalal</TD>
    <TD>papapap</TD>
    <TD>fafafa</TD>
    <TD>
    <form action=\"/addedUrl/;jsessionid=KJHSDFKJLSDF293847odhf" method=POST>
    <input type=hidden name=acT value=\"Dev\">
    <input type=hidden name=acA value=\"Anyval\">
    <input type=submit name=submit value=Stop>
    </form>
    </TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>`

    table := XMLTable{}
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", []byte(raw_html_table)[:15])
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(raw_html_table), &table)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

As an additional info, I don't care about cell content if it's HTML code (take only `[]byte` / `string` values). So I may delete cell content before unmarshaling, but this way is also not so easy.

Any suggestions with standard golang libs would be welcome.

Comment: Read about ",innerxml" in https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal

Comment: read already, but didn't catch the value :(

Comment: still get an error in XML. Goplay link https://play.golang.org/p/6wF0O_ORMO

Comment: You're escaping quotes inside backticks, which defeats the purpose of the backticks in Go. It inserts literal backslashes into your HTML before the quotes, which makes it invalid as HTML, let alone XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Sticking to the standard lib

Your input is not valid XML, so even if you model it right, you won't be able to parse it.

First, you're using a raw [string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) to define your input HTML as a `string`, and raw string literals cannot contain escapes. For example this:

```
<form action=\"/addedUrl/;jsessionid=KJHSDFKJLSDF293847odhf" method=POST>
```

You can't use `\"` in a raw string literal (you can, but it will mean exactly those 2 characters), and you don't have to, use a simple quotation mark: `"`.

Next, in XML you cannot have attributes without putting their values in quotes.

Third, each element must have a matching closing element, your `<input>` elements are not closed.

So for example this line:

```
<input type=hidden name=acT value=\"Dev\">
```

Must be changed to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="acT" value="Dev" />
```

Ok, after these the input is a valid XML now.

How to model it? Simple as this:

```
type XMLTable struct {
    Rows []struct {
        Cell string `xml:",innerxml"`
    } `xml:"TR>TD"`
}
```

And the full code to parse and print contents of `<TD>` elements:

```
raw_html_table := `
<TABLE><TR>
<TD>lalalal</TD>
<TD>papapap</TD>
<TD>fafafa</TD>
<TD>
<form action="/addedUrl/;jsessionid=KJHSDFKJLSDF293847odhf" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="acT" value="Dev" />
<input type="hidden" name="acA" value="Anyval" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Stop" />
</form>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>`

table := XMLTable{}
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(raw_html_table), &table)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
}

fmt.Println("count:", len(table.Rows))
for _, row := range table.Rows {
    fmt.Println("TD content:", row.Cell)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/G0oEy30fQL)):

```
count: 4
TD content: lalalal
TD content: papapap
TD content: fafafa
TD content: 
    <form action="/addedUrl/;jsessionid=KJHSDFKJLSDF293847odhf" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="acT" value="Dev" />
    <input type="hidden" name="acA" value="Anyval" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Stop" />
    </form>
```

#### Using a proper HTML parser

If you can't or don't want to change the input HTML, or you want to handle all HTML input not just valid XMLs, you should use a proper HTML parser instead of treating the input as XML.

Check out https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html for an HTML5-compliant tokenizer and parser.

Comment: thank you. As i mention earlier, i've got a raw html and try to simplify parsing using standard xml unmarshal. Seems like i need to change solution way and don't use xml lib with dynamic html tables. Anyway, your suggestion is quite full for me!

Answer (score 1):

Once your input is valid HTML (your snippet is missing quotes in attributes), you can configure a `xml.Decoder` with entities and autoclose maps (and make it non-strict), which will end up working :

[Run my modified version here](https://play.golang.org/p/UsuLsYhMRZm).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type XMLTable struct {
    Rows []struct {
        Cell string `xml:",innerxml"`
    } `xml:"TR>TD"`
}

func main() {
    raw_html_table := `
    <TABLE><TR>
    <TD>lalalal</TD>
    <TD>papapap</TD>
    <TD>fafafa</TD>
    <TD>
    <form action="/addedUrl/;jsessionid=KJHSDFKJLSDF293847odhf" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="acT" value="Dev">
    <input type="hidden" name="acA" value="Anyval">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Stop">
    </form>
    </TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>`

    table := XMLTable{}
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(raw_html_table))
    decoder.Entity = xml.HTMLEntity
    decoder.AutoClose = xml.HTMLAutoClose   
    decoder.Strict = false

    err := decoder.Decode(&table)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", table)
}
```